# Charles Proxy with sockets from Android App

Tags: android, sockets, reverse-engineering, charles-proxy

So i am trying to inspect an app ( bigo.tv ) and it is weirding me out.
I have Charles certificate installed , use an android 5.1 to not have to deal with the Nougat stuff.
The app has a login , but it is not showing as http nor https
so i thought it might be websockets ( wss:// ) i activated the socks proxy and it started showing these :
[image: sockets]
[image]
and all of them when i activate the proxy from ProxyDroid ( Socks5) they end up timing out,
while without the proxy , they don't show in Charles of course but they don't timeout.

Firstly : What is this Socket:// connection
Is it a normal inet socket ?
Secondly :
Is there anyway to intercept the traffic from that socket ?

Comment: They may have certificate pinning which will be preventing you from intercepting. For successful interception you may need to use a rooted device with additional stuff. See if the article https://vavkamil.cz/2019/09/15/how-to-bypass-android-certificate-pinning-and-intercept-ssl-traffic/ helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have a rooted device and i Unpinned the certificate 
using 3 different Xposed modules , and still no luck , i have dealt with certificate pinning before and unfortunately i don't think its the block here